# Bad Sorting a vector objects C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a strange problem when I try to sort vector of custom object. I have this code:

```
class Chromosome {
public:
   Chromosome(int c_w);       
   void setFitness(double fit);
   double getFitness() const;                
};
```

and compare function:

```
bool compareChromosomes(const Chromosome* l, const Chromosome* r) {
   return l->getFitness() <= r->getFitness();
}
```

I create the vector of chromosome: `vector<Chromosome*> popv;` and I add some chromosomes.

when I try to sort the vector with `sort(popv.begin(), popv.end(), compareChromosomes);`

this is the result:

BEFORE SORT:

cromosoma 0: 0.205595

cromosoma 1: 0.370121

cromosoma 2: 0.363655

cromosoma 3: 0.363655

**cromosoma 4: 0.858721**

cromosoma 5: 0.192359

cromosoma 6: 0.582279

cromosoma 7: 0.202899

cromosoma 8: 0.205105

cromosoma 9: 0.187058

AFTER SORT

**cromosoma 0: -0.474942**

cromosoma 1: 0.187058

cromosoma 2: 0.192359

cromosoma 3: 0.202899

cromosoma 4: 0.205105

cromosoma 5: 0.205595

cromosoma 6: 0.363655

cromosoma 7: 0.363655

cromosoma 8: 0.370121

cromosoma 9: 0.582279

where is the problem?

Comment: Try setting a memory breakpoint. Otherwise, the code isn't enough to tell.

Answer (score 4):

Your compare function is not strict - for two equal chromosomes, it returns `true` for `compareChromosomes` (regardless of order). Replace your condition with **strict less**:

```
bool compareChromosomes(const Chromosome* l, const Chromosome* r) {
   return l->getFitness() < r->getFitness();
   //                     |
   //                  <, not <=
}
```

Comment: You're right of course, but can this problem really explain the symptoms in the question?

Comment: @MarkRansom of course, if equality is checked as `compare(x,y) && compare(y,x)`.

Comment: I can see how that would produce an incorrect order, but how does it corrupt an element?

Comment: @MarkRansom oh dear :)). I thought the problem was incorrect ordering, I didn't see an element got changed. Hmmmm... can't really tell from the code.

Comment: I'm only guessing but since the corrupted value is the _greatest_ in the input dataset the incorrect compare function may cause the implementation to walk off the end of the container and cause the corruption.

Comment: I had changed from < to <= because I had this problem, but the result is the same. And the value corrupt is always the greatest.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why 0.858721 is changed to -0.474942 is not because of your comparison function.
There must be some other reason on the code you had not posted.
Try the code below: the output is ok.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Chromosome {
public:
  Chromosome(int c_w) :mCw(c_w) { }
  void setFitness(double fit) { mFit = fit; }
  double getFitness() const { return mFit; }
  int getCW() const { return mCw; }
private:
  int mCw;
  double mFit;
};

bool compareChromosomes(const Chromosome* l, const Chromosome* r) {
   return l->getFitness() <= r->getFitness();
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  // init your data
  vector<Chromosome *> popv;
  popv.push_back( new Chromosome( 0 ) );
  popv[ popv.size() - 1 ]->setFitness( 0.205595 );
  popv.push_back( new Chromosome( 1 ) );
  popv[ popv.size() - 1 ]->setFitness( 0.370121 );
  popv.push_back( new Chromosome( 2 ) );
  popv[ popv.size() - 1 ]->setFitness( 0.363655 );
  popv.push_back( new Chromosome( 3 ) );
  popv[ popv.size() - 1 ]->setFitness( 0.363655 );
  popv.push_back( new Chromosome( 4 ) );
  popv[ popv.size() - 1 ]->setFitness( 0.858721 );
  popv.push_back( new Chromosome( 5 ) );
  popv[ popv.size() - 1 ]->setFitness( 0.192359 );
  popv.push_back( new Chromosome( 6 ) );
  popv[ popv.size() - 1 ]->setFitness( 0.582279 );
  popv.push_back( new Chromosome( 7 ) );
  popv[ popv.size() - 1 ]->setFitness( 0.202899 );
  popv.push_back( new Chromosome( 8 ) );
  popv[ popv.size() - 1 ]->setFitness( 0.205105 );
  popv.push_back( new Chromosome( 9 ) );
  popv[ popv.size() - 1 ]->setFitness( 0.187058 );
  // sort
  sort( popv.begin(), popv.end(), compareChromosomes );
  for( size_t i = 0; i < popv.size(); i++ ) {
    cout << "cromosoma " << popv[i]->getCW() << ":" << popv[i]->getFitness() << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```